# find word & return whole string in excel?

Tags: excel

Hello I need to find a specific word in  text & return the whole string that the word is in.
Each string is in one excel cell.Thanks Dan

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you want to find the word in a specific cell range? If you are looking in  a single column of data like A1:A100 then you can use VLOOKUP, e.g. this formula will find the first cell that contains "word" and return everything from that cell

`=VLOOKUP("*word*",A1:A100,1,0)`